# Codeigniter: set_select() form validation for birthday picker jquery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Can anyone help me to figure out how can I use the `set_select()` Form helper in the [birthday picker jquery plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Customizable-Dropdown-Birthday-Picker-Plugin-with-jQuery.html)? What i want is if the validation fails the selected month, day and year stay after the page loads. Supposed to be the code needs to be injected in the option for the month only dropdown is

```
 <?php echo set_select('birth[month]', 'here is the value but it is dynamically generated by the plugin','the condition for update function in the future');  ?>
```

I already figured out to select the dropdowns based on the value in the database using for update function by setting the database value to a hidden input and getting the value through jquery
    $('select.birthMonth').find('[value='+myvariable+']').prop('selected',true);

The only problem is when the form validation fails birthdaypicker dropdowns reset to the default values. I cant use jquery to inject the

```
 <?php echo set_select('birth[month]', 'here is the value but it is dynamically generated by the plugin','the condition for update function in the future');  ?>
```

since the second parameter supposed to be for

```
set_select
```

is generated by jquery.

Note : im having problem with month, day and year. if i can figure the month only then it would be easy for other dropdowns. Days also vary per month.

If there are any alternatives other than this plugin, please feel free to comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set_select` is an helper to generate your selects, it's run BEFORE the view is rendered and your jquery is of course initialized after.

You can't use it here, you have to let the plugin handle the select boxes on its own.

According to the plugin's documentation page, you can set "defaultDate" when you initialize the plugin. My recommendation would be something like this when initializing your plugin (in javascript):

```
'var date = '.$this->input->post("year").'-'.$this->input->post("month").'-'.$this->input->post("day").';
$("#demo").birthdayPicker({
   defaultDate: date,
});'
```

You might need to check the value of `date` before actually using it, I made this quickly.

Comment: i guess the defaultDate option in this plugin runs only in the console. I tried what you suggested. And nothing happens in the dropdown.

Comment: I made some tests in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzf7f3rk/1/ and as it turns out, the format is not YYYY-MM-DD as I thought but MM-DD-YYYY.

Try changing the format to see what happens, but the defaultDate definitely works.

Comment: thank you for your help :) i updated the plugin that i have since the new fix was about defaultDate. Now it works.